# The difference between Plus and Minus

Tags: java

So i'm a newbie in Java and im just trying out simple stuff out in Java.
For Me This does not make much of a sense and google is not really helping me.

The Picture will probably tell my Problem exactly:

[image: GreenShot ScreeShot]

So i do not understand when you are doing a subtraction, why its not - and instead you still write the + sign.

if (userInput.hasNextInt())
        {

```
        int eingZahl = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Deine Eingegebene Zahl ist " + eingZahl);

        int plusRechnen = eingZahl + eingZahl;

        System.out.println(eingZahl + " + " + eingZahl + " = " + plusRechnen);

        int minusRechnen = eingZahl - eingZahl;

        System.out.println(eingZahl + " - " + eingZahl + " = " + minusRechnen);

    }

    else {

        System.out.println("Bitte Eine Zahl Eingeben!");
```

Comment: I understand that for plus you have to add a + sign, but for minus why is it sitl a + sign.

Comment: If you have code in your question, put it here as code and not as an image.

Comment: it's known as string concatenation this is nothing to do with the calculation of addition or subtraction. the `+` operator is overloaded meaning it will behave differently depending on the type of operands.

Comment: plusRechnen and minusRechnen are just variable names. you can name them to any.  but ensure you start using new names everywhere that is used.  + sign within system.out.println is for string concatenation

Comment: I added an image so it makes everything more clear, did know i also have to add the code, my bad.

Comment: `eingZahl + " - " + eingZahl + " = " + minusRechnen` will result in the _string_ (text) `"1 - 1 = 0"` if I input 1. The `+` here mean that the values are "added" into a string.

Comment: What should be result of "abc" - "124345"?

Comment: this question doesn't deserve the downvotes :)

Comment: @niceman "No research" is a valid downvote reason and to be honest every little beginner guide for java covers `+` for Strings. That `-` makes no sense in this context is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics the + operator is the addition operator so 1+2=3 and 3.5+1=4.5 etc.

Sometimes though we want to concat strings together so we want to print to the console the value of `eingZahl` followed by character `-` followed by `eingZahl` followed by `=` followed by `minusRenchen`.

Reasonably concat is a different operator than addition so it should have been different but Java instead uses `+` for concat, even if `+` sounds logical only for numbers still Java in string context interpret it as concat, so to acheive what we want we do this :

```
System.out.println(eingZahl + " - "+eingZahl + " = " + minusRenchen);
```

If you want to understand better Imagine that Java chose a unique operator for string concatenation like the dot for example : `eingZahl . " - " . eingZahl . " = " . minusRenchen`, php did this, Java didn't :) .

You can go far and say that adding a number to a string isn't reasonable as well but Java when you add anything to a string it convert this "anything" to a string and perform concat, this is a matter of convenience to let us express more in less words, otherwise we would have to write this :

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(eingZahl).concat(" - ").concat(Integer.toString(eingZahl)).concat(" = ").concat(Integer.toString(eingZahl)));
```

Obviously the first statement is more readable as long you remember what `+` does with strings.

By the way many languages let you put expressions right inside the string, something like this : `"$eingZahl - $eingZahl = $minusRenchen"` and result `"1-1=0"` when `eingZahl` equals 1, notable examples of those languages include some which can interoperate with java code seemlessly like Kotlin and Scala :) .

Answer (score 1):

'+' sign with the strings means you are going to join the two strings together. That is String Concatenation.
For example:

```
int a=10;
int b=5;
int c=a+b;
System.out.println(a +"+"+ b +"="+ c);
```

*The output is: 10+5=15*

In this example, the'+' sign next to the "quotation marks" makes the string concatenation. It will just show the values of he variable, no addition is done here.
The '+' sign in 'int c=a+b;' is the normal addition operation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
"a" + "b"
```

is string concatenation; resulting in "ab"

```
1 + 2
```

means: adding two numbers; resulting in 3.

You can add and subtract numbers, but strings can only be concatenated.

Comment: Yes i do understand that but as shown in the image when you want to subtract two numbers in the sysout you still write the " + " sign.

Comment: @Roobix13 "subtract two numbers in the sysout " - you don't subtract the numbers there, you only create a string and print it. The actual subtraction happens in `int minusRechnen = eingZahl - eingZahl;`.

Comment: @Roobix13 No, in the second part, all you're doing is concatenating strings and numbers. The subtraction was done at `int minusRechnen = eingZahl - eingZahl; `